# How to batch rearrange file names in OSX?

Tags: macos, file, rename, osx-yosemite

I am running OSX Yosemite.

I have a batch of files named in this format:
XX-YYYab.txt

The XX are variable numbers, as are the YYY. The 'a' and 'b' are variable letters.

I would like to rearrange the file name to get YYY-XXab.txt so that I can sort by the YYY component.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: You're probably looking for `rename`.

Comment: So far I've just used Finder's 'rename' tool in Yosemite to delete some prepending text. But that interface doesn't support wildcards.

Comment: Open a terminal window.  Type `man rename` ...

Comment: That sort of helped, but I don't really understand how to set up command to incorporate the parts of the file name and rearrange it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this in the Terminal - run it on a COPY of your files first in case it clobbers something.  Make sure to change directory to where your files are before you run it.

Save the following file as `renamethem`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loop through all files that start with digits, have dashes, and end in ".txt"
for f in [0-9]*-*.txt;do 

    # Get xx - the leading digits before a dash
    xx=${f/-*/}

    # Get yy - the digits after the dash
    yy=$(sed -E 's/.*-([0-9]*).*/\1/' <<< $f)

    # Get the letters before ".txt"
    zz=$(sed -E 's/.*[0-9](.*)\.txt/\1/' <<< $f)

    # DEBUG echo $xx, $yy, $zz

    # Remove the word "echo" below to do the actual rename
    echo mv "$f" "${yy}-${xx}${zz}.txt"
done
```

Then do the following just once to make it executable

```
chmod +x renamethem
```

Then run it by typing

```
/.renamethem
```

**Sample Output**

```
mv 12-345ab.txt 345-12ab.txt
mv 333333-9999axrt.txt 9999-333333axrt.txt
mv 45-3rm.txt 3-45rm.txt
```